# sql repeat rows for weekend and holidays

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A that we import based on the day that it lands on a location. We dont receive files on weekend and public holidays, and the table has multiple countries data so the public holidays vary. In essence we looking to duplicate a row multiple times till it encounters the next record for that ID (unless its the max date for that ID). A typical record looks like this:

```
Account Datekey Balance
1   20181012    100
1   20181112    100
1   20181212    100
1   20181512    100
1   20181712    100
```

And needs to look like this (sat, sun & PH added to indicate the day of week):

```
Account Datekey Balance 
1   20181012    100 
1   20181112    100 
1   20181212    100 
1   20181312    100 Sat
1   20181412    100 Sun
1   20181512    100 
1   20181612    100 PH
1   20181712    100
```

Also Datekey is numeric and not a date. I tried a couple solutions suggested but found that it simply duplicates the previous row multiple times without stopping when the next dates record is found. I need to run it as an update query that would execute daily on table A and add missing records when its executed (sometimes 2 or 3 days later).

Hope you can assist.

Thanks

Comment: Is your date key really in the format YYYYDDMM ???  If so, I think you might need another database designer.

Comment: unfortunately yes...

Comment: Is the key "Account + DateKey'? Do you have a table for weekends and holidays?

Comment: You really have the dates as yyyy**DD**mm?

Comment: `Also Datekey is numeric and not a date.` WHY? Did the designer only read Kimball? And [pre-2007 Kimball at that](http://kimballgroup.forumotion.net/t334-eliminate-date-dimension-surrogate-key#1401)? So many articles advice against this technique that is often considered infallible gospel, like [this one](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/05/date-vs-integer-datatypes-as-primary-key-for-date-dimensions/). So many advantages to using the right data type, and only false advantages to using the wrong one, IMHO.

Comment: is there a way to switch the format from yyyyDDmm to yyyyMMdd so it would comply to the iso standard ?

Answer (score 4):

This question has multiple parts:

- Converting an obscene date format to a date
- Generating "in-between" rows
- Filling in the new rows with the previous value
- Determining the day of the week

The following does most of this.  I refuse to regenerate the `datekey` format.  You really need to fix that.

This also assumes that your setting are for English week day names.

```
with t as (
      select Account, Datekey, Balance, convert(date, left(dkey, 4) + right(dkey, 2) + substring(dkey, 5, 2)) as proper_date
      from yourtable
     ),
     dates as (
      select account, min(proper_date) as dte, max(proper_date) as max_dte
      from t
      group by account
      union all
      select account, dateadd(day, 1, dte), max_dte
      from dates
      where dte < max_dte
     )
select d.account, d.dte, t.balance,
       (case when datename(weekday, d.dte) in ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
             then left(datename(weekday, d.dte), 3)
             else 'PH'
        end) as indicator
from dates d cross apply
     (select top (1) t.*
      from t
      where t.account = d.account and
            t.proper_date <= d.dte
      order by t.proper_date desc
     ) t
option (maxrecursion 0);
```